# Turn gps automatically when I open my maps activity

Tags: java, android, google-maps

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE");
intent.putExtra("enabled", true);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

I used the above code in my main java class but it did not work. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1):

This question is discussed many times. As I know, you can't do it automatically from Android 4.0.3. If you are using Android 2+, did you add following line to AndroidManifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

There is a different approach. That is use Google Settings API.

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0
```

Check [Google Samples](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/tree/master/LocationSettings)

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721449/how-can-i-enable-or-disable-the-gps-programmatically-on-android) question as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
LocationManager mlocationManager;
Boolean isGPSEnabled;

private static boolean checkGPSConnection(){
    if(mLocationManager == null)
        mLocationManager = (LocationManager) mcontext.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    isGPSEnabled = mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    return isGPSEnabled;
}
```

Use `checkGPSConnection()` method where you want to check GPS is available or not.

Answer (score -1):

In some devices you can't turn on/off GPS programmatically,
but there another great approach which will work in all devices(nonrooted/rooted). Just show dialog which open GPS settings where user can turn gps himself.

```
 public void statusCheck()
            {
                final LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService( Context.LOCATION_SERVICE );

                if ( !manager.isProviderEnabled( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER ) ) {
                    buildAlertMessageNoGps();

                }


            }
             private void buildAlertMessageNoGps() {
                    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                    builder.setMessage("Your GPS seems to be disabled, do you want to enable it?")
                           .setCancelable(false)
                           .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                               public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog,  final int id) {
                                   startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
                               }
                           })
                           .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                               public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, final int id) {
                                    dialog.cancel();
                               }
                           });
                    final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                    alert.show();

                }
```

Or try use this code to turn it automatically, but in some OS its will not work.

```
public void turnGPSOn()
{
     Intent intent = new Intent("android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE");
     intent.putExtra("enabled", true);
     this.ctx.sendBroadcast(intent);

    String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(ctx.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
    if(!provider.contains("gps")){ //if gps is disabled
        final Intent poke = new Intent();
        poke.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider"); 
        poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
        poke.setData(Uri.parse("3")); 
        this.ctx.sendBroadcast(poke);


    }
}
// automatic turn off the gps
public void turnGPSOff()
{
    String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(ctx.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
    if(provider.contains("gps")){ //if gps is enabled
        final Intent poke = new Intent();
        poke.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider");
        poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
        poke.setData(Uri.parse("3")); 
        this.ctx.sendBroadcast(poke);
    }
}
```