# how can i enable GPS without redirecting the user to the settings screen?

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-alloy

I would like to enable the location of the user as Google Maps does, it is possible in appcelerator studio? (without redirecting the user to the settings screen)

Answer (score 1):

You could try it with an intent:

```
Intent intent=new Intent("android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE");
intent.putExtra("enabled", true);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11503095/5193915

But I think it won't work on newer devices.

Comment: thanks, but it really doesn't work on new devices, and I need it.