# how I can turn on gps

Tags: android, android-location, android-gps

I want turn on gps automaticly when my application starts, like another applications. I have the below code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        LocationRequest mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(
                 LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    }
```

Permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: See [Changing Location Settings](https://developer.android.com/training/location/change-location-settings.html) and see       [SettingsApi](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/SettingsApi)

Comment: I tried but did not work

Comment: please show the code so we can see what might have gone wrong

Comment: You can see the codes

Comment: Just use code provider in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33555732/6134394) answer

Answer (score 0):

go to you application settings in the permission menu turn on GPS 
thats all
if you do not know how to go to application settings let me know i will send screenshots white explanations
best

Comment: I hope you send me some pictures my friend :]

Comment: go to setting -> apps->"choose your app"
https://dl2.pushbulletusercontent.com/LgmkIBCztc2eFZdQLT5llOo2p4M1zWO4/Screenshot_20170714-042830.png

Comment: I clicked Permissions and turn on Location but not working , But with other applications running I do not know why

Comment: Your questions is how to turn on GPS i answerd you
But what connected with locationservice there are bunch of topic in stackoverflow search it

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(InterviewListActivity.this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_CODE_FINE_LOC);
    }

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(InterviewListActivity.this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_CODE_COARSE_LOC);
    }

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
            Manifest.permission.LOCATION_HARDWARE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(InterviewListActivity.this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.LOCATION_HARDWARE}, REQUEST_CODE_LOC_HRD);
    }
```

Comment: Try to change the request code. In my answer they all have the same request code.

Comment: 2 weeks ago, I did not find a solution. I need you to help

Comment: Ok go ahead what you want