# How to programatically turn off GPS in andoid?

Tags: android, android-location, android-gps

I know this is a question that got asked a lot. But all of the answers I could find are very old so I wanted to ask again.

I want to turn off GPS services on the phone programmatically. What is the up to date answer to this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I enable or disable the GPS programmatically on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721449/how-can-i-enable-or-disable-the-gps-programmatically-on-android)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to turn off GPS

```
String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), 
    Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);

    if(provider.contains("gps")){
        final Intent poke = new Intent();
        poke.setClassName("com.android.settings", 
       "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider");
        poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
        poke.setData(Uri.parse("3")); 
        sendBroadcast(poke);
    }
```