# How can I reduce power usage and still GET location updates in a location-based Android application?

Tags: android, location

Problem:

1. I have an old Android 4 phone which I want to give to my child so that:

- he can call me when needed from school
- I could track his location if needed

2. for location tracking I would be happy with Google maps built-in option BUT it is not available for Android 4 anymore due to its 'planned obsolence' !!!

I tried this Google example code - https://github.com/android/location-samples/tree/master/ForegroundLocationUpdates:

- it works fine with default settings:

priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY

but it keeps my phone WARM and will DRAIN its battery in ~ 8 hours

- if I opt to:

priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY

then I never get updated location but only the old location.

Should I implement some auto-job e.g. with workmanager
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager
which will let's say 3-4 times per hour:

- switch on LocationRequest with PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY
- get updated location
- switch off LocationRequest till next scheduled time?

Or is there any other better solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Option 2 seems to be a finer way to implement and control it, But you will still end up losing battery when the GPS is left on.

Also would suggest you to look into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721449/how-can-i-enable-or-disable-the-gps-programmatically-on-android), There was an open bug on Android through which you can leverage the functionality of controlling GPS you wanted, That will work only if you are not on a patched version of the OS.